# Is it possible to check if NFC is enabled using as3/air?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, nfc

I think the title says it all however is it possible to detect using AS3 if a phones NFC adapter is enabled/disabled and then prompt the user to enable it?

Cheers

Comment: Currently testing on HTC One SV but the app will be for all NFC enabled devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Air does not have an NFC Api at the moment. (November 2013)

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2011-sneak-peeks/max-2011-sneak-peek-near-field-communications-in-adobe-air/

But you can use a Native extension to get this capability added to your app. Also, you can make NFC a requirement of you app in your applicationXML. The required android permission is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

or if you want it only avaiable to NFC devices in Google Play, use:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

Here is a roundup of NFC extensions available for AIR/Android:

http://flashdaily.net/post/42266463526/adobe-air-native-extensions-round-up

Answer (score -1):

here you can a free NFC native extension http://www.devactionscript.com/free-ane/near-field-communication-nfc-beam-ane-adobe-air-native-extensions-for-android/

Hope it helps !

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.